# How to use ORDER BY with multiple columns when usng GROUP BY and JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by

I am trying to execute the below query in Oracle 10g under the impression that we can specify column in the ORDER BY clause which is not in the SELECT list.

```
select d.DEPARTMENT_ID, count(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) 
from departments d, Employees e 
where d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID 
group by d.DEPARTMENT_ID 
order by d.DEPARTMENT_ID, e.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

But when i tried to execute above query i am getting the below error.

```
 [Error] Execution (1: 169): ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

When i remove the e.EMPLOYEE_ID from ORDER BY then the query is executing fine.

Please help me to identify what is wrong in the above query. Any help appreciated in advance.

Comment: query seems to get the total number of employees per dept, why would need to order it by `e.employee_id` as the result would just contain the total number of employees in a dept, no info about a particular employee or so

Comment: yes Akash you are right. we do not need to do order by using employee_id, but i am trying to find out what are the restrictions for columns to specify in the ORDER BY clause. As we can specify any columns from the tables specified even if it is not in the select list. when need to allow columns in the order by clause which are not in the select list?. please suggest any resources explaining the Oracle SQL query execution order step by step processing with tables data.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm):

> If you specify a group_by_clause in the same statement, then this
>   order_by_clause is restricted to the following expressions:
>
> - Constants
> - Aggregate functions
> - Analytic functions
> - The functions USER, UID, and SYSDATE
> - Expressions identical to those in the group_by_clause
> - Expressions comprising the preceding expressions that evaluate to the same value for all rows in a group

In other words if you have `GROUP BY` then you cannot `ORDER BY` by any column that is not part of `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this;

```
GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID 
ORDER BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID, e.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

`GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID` will result in a set of `e.EMPLOYEE_ID`s per department, which means that `ORDER BY ..., e.EMPLOYEE_ID` would be attempting to order by the set of ID's, not a specific ID.

One possible fix would be to use an aggregation function to pick a specific ID in the set to order by, for example `ORDER BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID, MAX(e.EMPLOYEE_ID);` would work.